# Skin Twitter HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, haml

I am building a twitter application and would like to use the structure of the their homepage. Can anyone suggest how to go about doing this, or point to a reference that does this?

I do not intend to use any images that would be considered copyright, I just want to use the single column layout, with the side panel, header, footer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is tagged haml, I'm assuming you're doing this on rails and know your way through haml. You can use Compass to make styling easier, it uses a combination of blueprint, 960 and yui and ports it to sass.

You can structure your html with

```
#container
  #header
  #main
    #content
    #sidebar
  #footer
```

then your sass with:

```
#container,
#header,
#footer
  +container

#main
  +container
  #content
    +column(16)
  #sidebar
    +column(8, true)
```

thats a basic one column layout with a right sidebar. You can then customize as you need to. Also read the Compass wiki for more info on styling/installing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for making a two-column layout with header and footer:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/